# Unable to stop suspect process even after reboot

Tags: linux, assembly

EDIT: As user gene mentioned i tried the following commands:

```
root@localhost:~# ps -axj | grep demo
warning: bad ps syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'?
See http://gitorious.org/procps/procps/blobs/master/Documentation/FAQ
```

I also tried without "-". After that it freezes. I also tried

```
ps -aux | grep demo
```

It freezes and nothing happens. Finally i tried

```
root@localhost:~# ps aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0  10664  1532 ?        Ss   21:37   0:00 init [2]  
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    21:37   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         3  1.1  0.0      0     0 ?        S    21:37   0:15 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         5  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   21:37   0:00 [kworker/0:0H]
root         7  0.3  0.0      0     0 ?        S    21:37   0:04 [rcu_sched]
root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    21:37   0:00 [rcu_bh]
root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    21:37   0:00 [migration/0]
root        10  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    21:37   0:00 [watchdog/0]
root        11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    21:37   0:00 [watchdog/1]
root        12  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    21:37   0:00 [migration/1]
root        13  0.9  0.0      0     0 ?        S    21:37   0:12 [ksoftirqd/1]
root        15  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   21:37   0:00 [kworker/1:0H]
root        16  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   21:37   0:00 [khelper]
root        17  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    21:37   0:00 [kdevtmpfs]
root        18  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   21:37   0:00 [netns]
root        19  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   21:37   0:00 [perf]
root        20  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    21:37   0:00 [khungtaskd]
root        21  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   21:37   0:00 [writeback]
root        23  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   21:37   0:00 [ksmd]
root        24  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   21:37   0:00 [khugepaged]
root        25  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   21:37   0:00 [crypto]
root        26  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   21:37   0:00 [kintegrityd]
root        27  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   21:37   0:00 [bioset]
root        28  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   21:37   0:00 [kblockd]
root        29  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   21:37   0:00 [devfreq_wq]
root        31  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    21:37   0:00 [kswapd0]
root        32  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    21:37   0:00 [fsnotify_mark]
root        39  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   21:37   0:00 [kthrotld]
root        41  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   21:37   0:00 [ipv6_addrconf]
root        42  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   21:37   0:00 [deferwq]
root       131  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   21:37   0:00 [ata_sff]
root       185  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    21:37   0:00 [scsi_eh_0]
root       186  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   21:37   0:00 [scsi_tmf_0]
root       187  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    21:37   0:00 [scsi_eh_1]
root       188  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   21:37   0:00 [scsi_tmf_1]
root       189  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    21:37   0:01 [kworker/u4:2]
root       191  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    21:37   0:00 [scsi_eh_2]
root       192  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   21:37   0:00 [scsi_tmf_2]
root       194  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    21:37   0:00 [scsi_eh_3]
root       195  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   21:37   0:00 [scsi_tmf_3]
root       196  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    21:37   0:00 [scsi_eh_4]
root       197  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    21:37   0:00 [kworker/u4:4]
root       198  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   21:37   0:00 [scsi_tmf_4]
root       199  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    21:37   0:00 [scsi_eh_5]
root       200  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   21:37   0:00 [scsi_tmf_5]
root       201  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    21:37   0:00 [kworker/u4:5]
root       213  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   21:37   0:00 [kworker/1:1H]
root       249  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   21:37   0:00 [kworker/0:1H]
root       250  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    21:37   0:00 [jbd2/sda1-8]
root       251  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   21:37   0:00 [ext4-rsv-conver]
root       398  0.0  0.1  21820  2728 ?        Ss   21:37   0:00 udevd --daemon
root       527  0.0  0.1  21684  2360 ?        S    21:37   0:00 udevd --daemon
root       534  0.0  0.1  21684  2360 ?        S    21:37   0:00 udevd --daemon
root       569  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   21:37   0:00 [edac-poller]
root       587  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   21:37   0:00 [kpsmoused]
root       600  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   21:37   0:00 [kvm-irqfd-clean]
root       605  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   21:37   0:00 [hd-audio0]
root       659  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   21:37   0:00 [cfg80211]
root       697  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   21:37   0:00 [ttm_swap]
root      2302  0.0  0.1  52920  2884 ?        Sl   21:37   0:00 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -c5
root      2310  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   21:37   0:00 [iprt]
daemon    2386  0.0  0.0  16684   152 ?        Ss   21:37   0:00 /usr/sbin/atd
root      2437  0.0  0.0  20424  1912 ?        Ss   21:37   0:00 /usr/sbin/irqbalance
root      2458  0.0  0.1  20356  2000 ?        Ss   21:37   0:00 /usr/sbin/cron
102       2476  0.0  0.1  30916  3104 ?        Ss   21:37   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system
root      2527  0.0  0.0  20936  1896 ?        Sl   21:37   0:00 /usr/sbin/pcscd
root      2530  0.0  0.4 175012  8252 ?        Ssl  21:37   0:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager
root      2574  0.0  0.3 145252  6648 ?        Sl   21:37   0:00 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkitd --no-debug
root      2578  0.0  0.2  80864  5116 ?        S    21:37   0:00 /usr/sbin/modem-manager
root      2580  0.0  0.2  31328  5256 ?        S    21:37   0:00 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /var/run/wpa_supplicant
root      2588  0.0  0.1  71140  2904 tty1     Ss   21:37   0:00 /bin/login --     
root      2589  0.0  0.0  14768  1760 tty2     Ss+  21:37   0:00 /sbin/getty 38400 tty2
root      2590  0.0  0.0  14768  1788 tty3     Ss+  21:37   0:00 /sbin/getty 38400 tty3
root      2591  0.0  0.0  14768  1828 tty4     Ss+  21:37   0:00 /sbin/getty 38400 tty4
root      2592  0.0  0.0  14768  1784 tty5     Ss+  21:37   0:00 /sbin/getty 38400 tty5
root      2593  0.0  0.0  14768  1788 tty6     Ss+  21:37   0:00 /sbin/getty 38400 tty6
root      2615  0.0  0.2   9972  5068 ?        S    21:37   0:00 /sbin/dhclient -d -4 -sf /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action -pf 
root      2620  0.0  0.3 129712  5972 ?        Sl   21:37   0:00 /usr/sbin/console-kit-daemon --no-daemon
root      2714  0.0  0.3  22636  6760 tty1     S    21:37   0:00 -bash
root      2839  0.0  0.2  83900  5508 tty1     Sl+  21:38   0:00 gdm3
root      2840  0.0  0.3 105324  7480 tty1     Sl+  21:38   0:00 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-simple-slave --display-id /org/gnome/DisplayManager/Displ
root      2842  3.7  1.1 148308 21944 tty7     Ss+  21:38   0:47 /usr/bin/Xorg :0 -br -verbose -novtswitch -auth /var/run/gdm3/auth-for-Debi
root      2865  0.0  0.2 140064  5476 ?        Sl   21:38   0:00 /usr/lib/accountsservice/accounts-daemon
root      2887  0.0  0.3 166216  6724 ?        Sl   21:38   0:00 /usr/lib/upower/upowerd
rtkit     3009  0.0  0.1  39648  2136 ?        SNl  21:38   0:00 /usr/lib/rtkit/rtkit-daemon
root      3064  0.0  0.3 184864  7140 tty1     Sl+  21:38   0:00 gdm-session-worker [pam/gdm3]
root      3070  0.0  0.3 125988  7676 tty1     Sl+  21:38   0:00 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login
root      3072  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    21:38   0:00 [kauditd]
root      3088  0.0  0.9 277492 17796 ?        Ssl  21:38   0:00 x-session-manager
root      3133  0.0  0.0  24200  1740 ?        S    21:38   0:00 dbus-launch --autolaunch=1ed4d2506ef17dbeabe06d1256281459 --binary-syntax -
root      3134  0.0  0.0  29816  1868 ?        Ss   21:38   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-pid 5 --print-address 7 --session
root      3137  0.0  0.2 133008  4712 ?        Sl   21:38   0:00 /usr/lib/dconf/dconf-service
root      3150  0.0  0.0  12480   332 ?        Ss   21:38   0:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session x-session-manag
root      3153  0.0  0.0  24200  1820 ?        S    21:38   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session x-session-manager
root      3154  0.0  0.1  30688  2868 ?        Ss   21:38   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-pid 5 --print-address 7 --session
root      3161  0.1  1.5 524844 29624 ?        Sl   21:38   0:02 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gnome-settings-daemon
root      3172  0.0  0.2  62276  5164 ?        S    21:38   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd
root      3176  0.0  0.3  73376  6864 ?        S    21:38   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-gdu-volume-monitor
root      3178  0.0  0.3 129704  5824 ?        Sl   21:38   0:00 /usr/lib/udisks/udisks-daemon
root      3179  0.0  0.0  47424   340 ?        S    21:38   0:00 udisks-daemon: not polling any devices
root      3182  0.0  0.2  60464  5092 ?        S    21:38   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor
root      3184  0.0  0.2  78896  5652 ?        Sl   21:38   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-afc-volume-monitor
colord    3187  0.0  0.3 152212  7028 ?        Sl   21:38   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/colord/colord
root      3190  0.3  1.2 379304 23744 ?        Sl   21:38   0:04 /usr/bin/metacity
root      3196  0.0  0.4 234908  8620 ?        Sl   21:38   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-printer
root      3200  0.7  2.3 486648 46160 ?        Sl   21:38   0:09 gnome-panel
colord    3203  0.0  0.6 260036 13420 ?        Sl   21:38   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/colord/colord-sane
root      3216  0.0  0.2  54304  5760 ?        S    21:38   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconf/gconfd-2
root      3219  0.0  0.2 133008  4768 ?        Sl   21:38   0:00 /usr/lib/dconf/dconf-service
root      3223  0.0  1.2 368236 24560 ?        Sl   21:38   0:00 gnome-sound-applet
root      3224  0.0  0.8 180136 16008 ?        Sl   21:38   0:00 /usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1
root      3225  0.1  0.7 200268 14412 ?        Sl   21:38   0:02 /usr/lib/tracker/tracker-store
root      3226  0.0  0.8 256348 17148 ?        Sl   21:38   0:00 gnome-screensaver
root      3232  0.0  1.0 277024 20640 ?        Sl   21:38   0:00 bluetooth-applet
root      3233  0.3  2.0 539100 39096 ?        Sl   21:38   0:04 nautilus -n
root      3234  0.0  0.8 268208 17072 ?        Sl   21:38   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gnome-fallback-mount-helper
root      3235  0.0  1.4 327748 27464 ?        Sl   21:38   0:00 nm-applet
root      3246  0.0  0.8 184252 16848 ?        Sl   21:38   0:00 /usr/lib/notification-daemon/notification-daemon
root      3249  0.0  0.5 239228  9832 ?        S<l  21:38   0:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start
root      3250  0.1  1.3 212688 26000 ?        SNl  21:38   0:02 /usr/lib/tracker/tracker-miner-fs
root      3256  0.0  0.9 196068 17804 ?        S    21:38   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-disk-utility/gdu-notification-daemon
root      3270  0.0  0.3  70988  6516 ?        S    21:38   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-trash --spawner :1.6 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/0
root      3272  0.0  0.2  62152  5516 ?        S    21:38   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-burn --spawner :1.6 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/1
root      3280  0.0  0.3  61940  6184 ?        S    21:38   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-metadata
root      3286  0.0  0.5 191048 10140 ?        Sl   21:38   0:00 /usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5
root      3290  0.0  1.0 293992 20268 ?        Sl   21:38   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-online-accounts/goa-daemon
root      3299 15.2 14.8 970352 285392 ?       Sl   21:38   3:06 iceweasel
root      3312  0.0  0.3 159984  6224 ?        Sl   21:38   0:00 /usr/lib/at-spi2-core/at-spi-bus-launcher
```

I cant see any name "demo" and after the last line it also freezes :S

I dont really know if this is a programming related question but to me it seems like. I am learning assembly and wrote a very simple program, just shifting bits and registers around. I called the file ./demo.

That was yesterday, today my computer hang up periodicly on firefox and/or google js. I dont really know so i take a look at developer console but after that my browser totally died. Ok i took a look at

```
lsof -i
```

just to see whats happening on my network. Then i recognized an "established connection" (i know udp is not really a connection, but i guess its listening to something

```
demo     3548 root   16u  IPv4  74799      0t0  UDP 192.168.0.14:53459->viedns09.chello.at:domain
```

chello.at is my ISP but i never had a process like this before.

The file i had created yesterday was named ./demo. Even after deleting it and kill the process, its still there. I also cant access

```
cat /proc/3548/maps
```

If i do that my computer hang up. Maybe some of you could help me, it really kind of scares me.

My .asm code was simply this

```
start:
    add $1, %eax
    push %rax
    jmp start
```

of course i played around a bit so i changed the code a few times. I dont know which version was the one that causes the problem but all versions i've written was similar to that. No sockets or something like that.

Comment: uh, maybe a script killing the process every 10seconds could help, that's strange XD

Comment: It wasnt even networking code, just some simple beginner arithmetics. Killing the process with a script every 10 sec isnt a solution to me, sorry. I have closed this specific ports for now, but i really need to know whats going on and how to solve it. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: Could you add maybe dôme liens from your assembly?

Comment: Sorry, google translates "dôme liens" into "dome links" but i dont understand whats that. I have added the .asm code. Nothing special, just a counter writing numbers on the stack.

Comment: Power off your PC by unplugging it. If you have a laptop, unplug it and remove the battery. If the processes is still there then its likely some other process that has nothing to do with the code you wrote, it just happens to share the same name. The UDP connection you see is pretty innocuous. It's just for DNS.

Comment: Just do `ps -axj | grep demo` and look at the column with path to executable (I think it's the 11th).  This will tell you which "demo" is running.

Comment: Gene, thanks but no success, i've added the outputs to my question :S @Ross Ridge i have unplugged it about 30 times since yesterday, it still appears. Also as whois mentioned its a static dns server of my isp but i have a dynamic ip and that "service" never shows up before.

Comment: Might try asking it over at server fault:  http://serverfault.com/